# PHP array_merge or array_unique and closures

Tags: php, arrays, closures

Can I merge an array, or remove duplicates from an array in PHP >=5.4 using a closure, in the same fashion as it can be done in Objective C using a block, or in C++ using a lambda ?

- Is it possible to use a predicate/closure/block/lambda as a parameter to such functions.

I.e:

```
$a = array('blah','bleh');
$b = array('blih, 'bloh');
$arr = array_merge( function() use (&$a,&$b) { return $a == $b ? true : false; } );
```

(Above example is oversimplified, I want to do this for Objects).

- Can it be done inline or should I always define the closure as an
  $var ?
- Is there a performance gain, or does it run the same ?

Comment: You'd probably use array_filter with a closure to eliminate duplicates; and yes, it is perfectly possible with an array of objects

Comment: Thank you @MarkBaker make an answer and you'll get the kudos :) Is that the right syntax btw ?

Comment: @Alex .. what would be the expected output since you want to merge not filter ...  ?

Comment: @Baba in this case an array of merged arrays of objects without duplicates I would hope.

Comment: So, `array_unique(array_merge())`?

Comment: Why not use `array_unique` ?

Comment: How would you "merge an array" "in Objective C using a block, or in C++ using a lambda"?

Comment: @deceze  array_unique( array_merge()) assumes Objects implement __toString() which is not sufficient in my case, as I would like to use a closure to make the comparison on a per-Object case. An alternative I imagine would be a class operator (similar to C++ == or !=, etc.).

Comment: @newacct Although not merging, its an idea of something similar: [self.array objectAtIndex: [self.array indexOfObjectPassingTest:
^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){                                                           Observations *obs = (Observations*)obj;                                                                                                  return [obs.TIME  isEqualToString:keyword];}]];}
In C++11 similar things can be done using closures.

Comment: @Alex: so this is "searching for an element"? I am confused because `array_merge` is used to merge or concatenate two arrays. Searching is completely unrelated.

Comment: @newacct yes, this is for filtering elements. Of course its unrelated :) The question (what I was curious about in any case) was if I could use closures for this sort of operations. A similar thing could be carried out by filtering unique elements and merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use array_filter() for this. My guess is that you need to filter 1 array as parameter and add the second array as use(). When the current value is not in the array passed in use(), you can add it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

This only if you need to check based on a value inside the object ofc as $a == $b can be tricky with objects ;)

Comment: Huh, that is very interesting. Thank you for linking this, I see they already used a function callback, I assume I could just pass a closure to this as well? Kudos for the cleanest solution

Comment: Closures and callables are a bit off in PHP. Here's some more information regarding callables. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

As of 5.4 the type Callable has been added and as of 5.3 closures have been added. Before that you had specific functions which allowed a 'function_name' or array($my_obj, 'method_name') to be faked into a 'callable' parameter.